# double request from omniauth (devise, custom strategy, oauth2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, devise

I have some oauth provider code, based on one taken from here:
http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/

Then I created my client with omniauth custom strategy + devise (also somehow based on link mentioned earlier).

However I have problem - it seems like my strategy is being called twice, and method auth_hash is called twice, which results in double call being made to access_token_url and user.json.

Any idea why it is called twice and how to prevent it?

Comment: Hi! I think it would help to see some code, and your `routes.db` file. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is solved - an issue was requiring strategy file twice: first time in omniauth.rb and second time in devise.rb.

Comment: It'd be great to see this added as an answer so that the question can be closed and people can see more readily your solution to the issue.

Comment: This has been in the top list for unanswered questions for a while now. You should add an answer (even a rudimentary one) and accept it, so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved - an issue was requiring strategy file twice: first time in omniauth.rb and second time in devise.rb.